# Dash, circular callback inputs

Tags: callback, infinite-loop, plotly-dash

I have a problem with an application I want to code with Dash. I have two different checklists (indicator A, indicator B). My goal is that the user can choose multiple options for only one indicator. So it is allowed to choose a,b,c and 1. It should also be possible to select c and 2,3 at the same time. The selection of a,c and 1,2 on the other hand, should be prevented. My approach to this is the following code:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label('indicator A'),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id = 'i_a',
        options=[
            {'label': 'a', 'value': 'a'},
            {'label': 'b', 'value': 'b'},
            {'label': 'c', 'value': 'c'}
        ],
        value = ['a']
    ),
    html.Label('indicator B'),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id='i_b',
        options=[
            {'label': '1', 'value': '1'},
            {'label': '2', 'value': '2'},
            {'label': '3', 'value': '3'}
        ],
        value=['1']
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('i_b', 'value'),
    Input('i_a', 'value')
)
def change_b(value_a):
    return ['1']

@app.callback(
    Output('i_a', 'value'),
    Input('i_b', 'value')
)
def change_b(value_b):
    return ['a']
```

This creates an endless loop because the callbacks trigger each other. However, I have no idea how to solve the problem. I am grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the new [circular callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks) ability. Check out the examples on this page, which I think are very similar to what you're doing.